# Test result of command match with false or true

Tags: powershell, active-directory, powershell-3.0

I'm looking for a function that returns `$true` or `$false` according to the result of command.

Little bit like this:

```
Function Get-ChPwd ([string] $sam) {
    $x = Get-ADUser -Identity $sam -Properties CannotChangePassword |
         Select-Object -ExpandProperty CannotChangePassword

    if( $x -match "False") {
        return $false
    } else {
        return $true
    }
}
```

Comment: `if( $x -match "False")` is not the same as `if( $x -match $False)` which is what you meant... that and ansgars answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The property already has a boolean value, so you can simply return that value. I would recommend a different function name, though, so it adheres to the [naming conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms714428(v=vs.85).aspx).

```
Function Test-CannotChangePassword([string]$sam) {
    Get-ADUser -Identity $sam -Properties CannotChangePassword |
        Select-Object -ExpandProperty CannotChangePassword
}
```

Note that this will raise an error if no user with that identity exists. If you want to return `$false` instead of throwing an error in that case use `-Filter` instead of `-Identity` and cast the result to bool:

```
Function Test-CannotChangePassword([string]$sam) {
    [bool](Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -eq '$sam'" -Properties CannotChangePassword |
        Select-Object -ExpandProperty CannotChangePassword)
}
```